# Remove almost duplicate records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Starting from this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,Manufacturer,Model,RevisionID FROM dbo.COMPUTER_TABLE ORDER BY Name,RevisionID
```

I get to the following table:

```
(Name,Manufacturer,Model,RevisionID)

UST8923 | Microsoft | Surface 2 | 1
UST8923 | Microsoft | Surface 2 | 2
UST8923 | Microsoft | Surface 3 | 3
UST8923 | Microsoft | Surface 3 | 4
CAD4258 | Lenovo | Thinkpad P1 | 1
CAD4258 | Lenovo | Thinkpad P1 | 2
CAD4258 | Dell | Latitude 5480 | 3
```

I need to get only the records with the highest RevisionID and discard the rest.
So, I need to get this result:

```
UST8923 | Microsoft | Surface 3 | 4
CAD4258 | Dell | Latitude 5480 | 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you only need those four columns you can group by `Name,Manufacturer,Model` and apply `max(RevisionID)`. Otherwise do `row_number() over (partition by Name,Manufacturer,Model order by RevisionID desc) as rn` in a CTE and filter `where rn = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY Name, Manufacturer`

```
SELECT 
  Name,
  Manufacturer, 
  MAX(Model) AS MaxModel,
  MAX(RevisionID) AS MaxRevisionID 
FROM dbo.COMPUTER_TABLE 
GROUP BY Name, Manufacturer
ORDER BY Name, MAX(Model), MAX(RevisionID)
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my initial question, it seems records are not always duplicate.

Comment: Try my edited answer

Comment: Why do you exclude the `Thinkpad P1` lines?

Comment: Because I just want the highest RevisionID row for each Name.

Comment: What about the other columns Manufacturer and Model? Did you try Gordon Linoff's answer?

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is a simple and efficient solution:

```
select ct.*
from dbo.COMPUTER_TABLE ct
where ct.revisionid = (select max(ct2.revisionid)
                       from COMPUTER_TABLE ct2
                       where ct2.name = ct.name
                      );
```